# Coordinate Connecting

Tags: code-golf, geometry, sorting, path-finding

**Input:**

Ten unique integer coordinates, between `(0,0)` and `(100,100)`.

**Output:**

The coordinates arranged in the order/an order such that a path drawn between the coordinates in that order is the shortest path possible.

This is code golf so the shortest code wins!

Comment: I cleaned up the formatting a little, feel free to roll back if you preferred the old one. I removed the word "random", since usually random would indicate that the program has to be nondeterministic.

Comment: Could we get some test cases?

Comment: I replaced 'line' with 'path'. Please clarify if this is not what you intended.

Comment: FYI this is like the [Travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) except you don't return to the initial point to complete the loop.

Comment: 10 numbers should have 10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1 =3,628,800 solutions, maybe could be an issue for some programming languages

Comment: The number would actually be half that as you could reverse the order and have the same length path.

Comment: @qazwsx Nobody is going to do that in a code-golf challenge. If it was fastest-code on the other hand…

Comment: This is similar to the 'travelling salesman' problem, but it is *not* a duplicate of the previous code-golf 'travelling salesman' challenge (different format, different scoring).

Comment: @qazwsx I have some cases where floating point errors make the shortest path be shorter in one direction than in the reversed order, so no you'd have to count all the solutions to make sure. Case in point: `(87, 3) (70, 20) (70, 22) (67, 39) (70, 44) (62, 89) (47, 59) (40, 40) (42, 31) (7, 15)` has length 196.3336221458198 while the reverse `(7, 15) (42, 31) (40, 40) (47, 59) (62, 89) (70, 44) (67, 39) (70, 22) (70, 20) (87, 3)` has length 196.33362214581976.

Comment: My downvote will become an upvote as soon as you post a couple of test cases

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 40 bytes

```
MinimalBy[ArcLength@*Line]@*Permutations
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zczLzM3McepMtqxKNknNS@9JMNByyczLzXWQSsgtSi3tASoND@v@H9AUWZeib5DmoNrcka@g5@DslpdcHJiXl1QYl5Kfq5nXklqempRdLWBjqGBQa1OtamOuY5Rbex/AA) (7 points)

Times out for longer inputs.

Accepts a list of points with *approximate-number* coordinates.

To accept exact (`Integer`) input, **+3 bytes**:

```
MinimalBy[N@*ArcLength@*Line]@*Permutations
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zczLzM3McepMtrPQcuxKNknNS@9JMNByyczLzXWQSsgtSi3tASoOj@v@H9AUWZeib5DmoNrcka@g7JaXXByYl5dUGJeSn6uZ15JanpqUXS1gY6hgUGtTrWpjrmOUW3sfwA)

This is because `MinimalBy` uses Mathematica's canonical ordering, which compares objects structurally, rather than numerical ordering. Thus, for example, `3` is "less than"  `1+Sqrt[2]`. This is only an issue when using exact numbers, where the length can include `Sqrt`s.

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to a [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218055/95126) from Leo*

```
◄oṁ√Ẋδṁo□-P
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9H0lvyHOxsfdcx6uKvr3BYgM//RtIW6Af///4@ONtYxjNUBkkZA0lDHAEgagUkDsIgBWNZIxxgsaxwbCwA) (with only 8 points to avoid timing-out...)

**How?**

```
          P  # from all permutations of the input
◄o           # get the one that minimizes the result of
  ṁ√         # sum of all the square roots of
    Ẋ        # applying to all adjacent sets of coordinates
     δṁo     # sum of all the
        □-   # squares of the differences
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <sup><s>107</s></sup> 100 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
f=head.sortOn(sum.(zipWith(\(x,y)(m,n)->sqrt$(x-m)^2+(y-n)^2)<*>tail)).permutations
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYo7C8IwFEZ3f4VDh3s1DX2stpOj4OjgAwK29GKSxuQWWv98DFnOd/g4kwqfQesYybjZ8/6sWMkLBd6N3TSotwzpvVoIi5HwI3cjnuABq9gQjLBY9uHruYC1NPhqjrCVNi2eDj0r0ojSDd4srJhmG6JRZDvnyXIx3qESNQpoRZPYiDazSqyz19nb3FSpecY/)

*-7 by @xnor and @benrg*

Comment: Can you remove the `sqrt`? - I think sort order will still be preserved

Comment: `foldr` seems like overkill. I'd expect `zipWith` and `sum` would be shorter.

Comment: `f=head.sortOn(sum.(zipWith(\(x,y)(m,n)->sqrt$(x-m)^2+(y-n)^2)<*>tail)).permutations` saves 7 bytes (as suggested by xnor). `f=head.sortOn(\p->sum[sqrt$(x-m)^2+(y-n)^2|(m,n)<-p|(x,y)<-tail p]).permutations` saves another 3 bytes but requires `-XParallelListComp` and I don't know if that has to be counted.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Not when you're summing it up afterward. 9+16 < 1+25, but √9+√16 > √1+√25.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
œΣü-nOtO}н
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6ORziw/v0c3zL/GvvbD3///oaAMdBYNYHQUQbQiiDRF8IxBtBOUbIviGUNooNhYA) Times out on TIO with 10 coordinates.

**Commented**:

```python
œ             # all permutations of the coordinates
 Σ       }    # sort on ...
  ü           #   for each pair of adjacent coordinates ...
   -          #     take the element-wise difference
    nOt       #   Euclidean norm for each difference (square, sum, square root)
       O      #   sum all distances
         н    # take the first element
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 124 bytes

Processing 10 points on TIO takes about 35 seconds.

```javascript
f=(a,X,Y,d=m=1/0,p=[])=>a.map(([x,y],i)=>f(a.filter(_=>i--),x,y,1/d&&d+Math.hypot(x-X,y-Y),[...p,[x,y]]))+a?o:d>m||(m=d,o=p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BasMwEETv/Yo9BW2zUqxry7r4A3pPMCIskd04WJZQTIjB/@64PhZ6nDfDm5s85H7JXRr1EH2zLC0roSOdyHNgeygoce2QSzFBklL1kyZH3QpaJabt@rHJ6sxlpzXS2pE9@N3O779lvJrrlOKonvpIkz4h1caYRJvBIe7lK374MsyzCuwpcsKlAobfVZWzTMoW6LbXM3AJNWzOLIOPQSG8gy0szFDQfwU4/Hy7xOEe@8b08UdVf3K7Elxe)

#### Commented

A recursive function that tries all permutations of the input points, computing the length of the path for each of them and keeping track of the shortest one.

```javascript
f = (                   // f is a recursive function taking:
  a,                    //   a[] = input
  X, Y,                 //   (X, Y) = coordinates of the previous point
  d = m = 1 / 0,        //   d = total distance, m = minimum distance
                        //   (both initialized to +Infinity)
  p = []                //   p[] = current path
) =>                    //
a.map(([x, y], i) =>    // for each point (x, y) at position i in a[]:
  f(                    //   do a recursive call:
    a.filter(_ => i--), //     with the i-th entry removed from a[]
    x, y,               //     using (x, y) as the previous point
    1 / d               //     set the distance d to 0 if this is the 1st point
    &&                  //     otherwise:
      d +               //       update d by adding
      Math.hypot(       //       the Euclidean distance between
        x - X, y - Y    //       the points (X, Y) and (x, y)
      ),                //
    [...p, [x, y]]      //     append the point (x, y) to the path
  )                     //   end of recursive call
)                       // end of map()
+ a ?                   // if a[] is not empty:
  o                     //   just return o[]
:                       // else (complete path):
  d > m                 //   unless the new distance is greater than m,
  || (m = d, o = p)     //   update m to d and set the output o[] to p[]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 213 bytes

```java
l->{double d=1e9,e;var r=l.clone();for(int i=0,z,x[]=new int[10];i<10;)if(x[i]<i){var t=l[z=i%2*x[i]++];l[z]=l[i];l[i]=t;for(e=z=i=0;z<9;)e+=l[z].distance(l[++z]);if(e<d){d=e;r=l.clone();}}else x[i++]=0;return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJLj5swEL7nV8ylkllYC/a2axypUrVqD5Wq5og4eMFknRobGZMHEb89HRMSrdoeesL@5nvMDN6JvXjc1b8uqu2s87DDOx280vSBrf7CmsFUXlnzZ1EcPN1K2wa80qLv4btQBs4rgG5406qC3guPn71VNbRYIxvvlNkWJQi37aOZCvC6@Oc/rDL@6UtRJvfTGhp@0Y/rc23RUkLNM/mcSLYXDhzXtNLWSBKxxjqCElA8TcbkWJTcyAMgUmRpyVSepSxSDTkWqsxVdA5yz3UxcvXp6SGgcVwyvJcIqnBSJfezq@RI4ikb82cWyTiISlorHM1UkugijscyYugt8zo611yyj31Nk9S9BEzAAHRx0g/OgGPThc3Dz4MIU9sWOISef84XlN7LXVhGv5S/iv59I/1tV@sb8fCucD3kyqW9GjEdcsjS25Zh8aGirklwWhzoq7bCk2sP1Mij/2Y8ydIsSuAfYLTkTff2hHPihN0t9t5@DgC5/8KXF0xbVJtT72VL7eBphy/Ba0NmdpBd3waZ7aIP4zvZD9pjQENF1@nTwvhvw6v@6jitpstv)

It takes roughly 1 second to process.

### Explanations

This is basically the [iterative heap's algorithm](https://www.baeldung.com/java-array-permutations#2-iterative-algorithm) with the distance computation and comparison integrated, because there are no native way to get permutations and because recursion in Java is expensive, byte-wise.

I'm using `java.awt.geom.Point2D` which has a `distance(Point2D)` method but it's not reflected in the code since I try by all means to avoid writing such a long class name to spare bytes. This is why I use `l.clone()` twice and `var t`.

Comment: I can't verify it's correct because there are no test cases.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
Œ!ÆịạƝSƊÞḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJMXDbQ93dz/ctfDY3OBjXYfnPdyx6P///9HRBjqGsTrRxjpGQNJIxxhMGgBJQzDbEMw2BqsxAKqJBQA)

Test case is 8 points arranged into a pseudo-regular octagon. TIO times out on 10 points, but the program should work in theory.

### Explanation

```
Œ!ÆịạƝSƊÞḢ   Main monadic link
Œ!           Permutations
        Þ    Sort by
       Ɗ     (
  Æị           Convert to complex numbers
    ạ          Absolute difference
     Ɲ           of each neighboring pair
      S        Sum
       Ɗ     )
         Ḣ   First element
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>138</s>, 135 bytes

Saved **3 Bytes** due to a suggestion from Noodle9 to use `lambda` instead of `print`!

```python
lambda a:min(permutations(a),key=lambda p:sum([sum([(p[i][j]-p[i+1][j])**2for j in 0,1])**.5for i in range(9)]))
from itertools import*
```

Essentially, this program loops through all possible `permutations` of the path and prints the path with the minimum length. The `key` argument of the `min` function is a `lambda` function that calculates the sum of the "distance" between consecutive points in `p`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY1NbsIwEIX3OcXssNMB2SapHKT0ImkWrkiKAf/IHhacPrURJ@jme6NPT2/iky7Bq20dv7e7cT9nA@bkrGdxSe5BhmzwmRmOt@U5vgvxlB@OTS@wONl5us77kh@yXrxt1RoSXMF6ECirOPTV2GqS8b8LG/jMebOm4MDSkiiEewbrYkjUbgQjTEyg4MgUdoUSVWGHn4U96kKNQ@GA6lUSqGpNC9THmhJ1x@cml6GVEW9isp6AEHaw/4IdQt7e@xLFof/vhz8)

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by making the whole answer a `lambda` like [this](https://tio.run/##LYzLDsIgFET3/Yq7E@o1oVgNNak/UrvA2CpVHoHrwq@vYNycmUxOJnzo4Z1c5/6yvrS93jTokzWOhSnaN2ky3iWmOT6nT/8Xwim9LRtYGMw4LOMu57Ypjde1nH0EA8ZB1O4@sY6XYSmDwGbkvJqjt2BoiuT9K4GxwUeqV4IeBiZQcGQS28wGZWaLx8wDqkyFXWaH8icJlEVTAtW@ZIOq5WOV8tHMiFchGkdACBvYnWGDkNYv).

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. But a sqrt is needed. I mistakenly believed it wasn't needed but I saw a comment explaining that it was.

Comment: You'll have to add `sqrt` to your original answer too so what does that have to do with my suggested golf?

Comment: @Noodle9 Just added it right before I read your comment. Sorry, I wasn't trying to criticise. I was just saying that I wouldn't be able to use your exact answer.

Comment: np.That's an interesting point about the order of the sums of the `sqrt`s being different to the order of the sums.